# Add UIImageView on UIScrollView while UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have UIViewController which has UIScrollView on it. The UIScrollView has various tile Images like Apple Developer tile image layer program. I am trying to use UITapGestureRecognizer to know the location and place a uiimageview with uiimage on top of it. But somehow it never places the image file.

```
- (void)loadView 
{    
CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];
pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
pagingScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
pagingScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
pagingScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
pagingScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
pagingScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
pagingScrollView.contentSize = [self contentSizeForPagingScrollView];
pagingScrollView.delegate = self;
self.view = pagingScrollView;


UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
[pagingScrollView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
self.tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
recognizer.delegate = self;
[recognizer release];

recycledPages = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
visiblePages  = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[self tilePages];

[pagingScrollView addSubview:imageView]; /// **** Here I am Adding to ScrollView *****//

}

- (void)showImageWithText:(NSString *)string atPoint:(CGPoint)centerPoint {

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
imageView.center = centerPoint;
imageView.alpha = 1.0;  
 }


- (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:pagingScrollView];

int tapX = (int) location.x;
    int tapY = (int) location.y;
    [self showImageWithText:@"tap" atPoint:location];

   }

  //****More Code  Same code like TilingLayer.m from Apple Developer Kit ****//
- (void)tilePages 
 {
  // Calculate which pages are visible
CGRect visibleBounds = pagingScrollView.bounds;
int firstNeededPageIndex = floorf(CGRectGetMinX(visibleBounds) / CGRectGetWidth(visibleBounds));
int lastNeededPageIndex  = floorf((CGRectGetMaxX(visibleBounds)-1) / CGRectGetWidth(visibleBounds));
firstNeededPageIndex = MAX(firstNeededPageIndex, 0);
lastNeededPageIndex  = MIN(lastNeededPageIndex, [self imageCount] - 1);

// Recycle no-longer-visible pages 
for (ImageScrollView *page in visiblePages) {
    if (page.index < firstNeededPageIndex || page.index > lastNeededPageIndex) {
        [recycledPages addObject:page];
        [page removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
[visiblePages minusSet:recycledPages];

// add missing pages
for (int index = firstNeededPageIndex; index <= lastNeededPageIndex; index++) {
    if (![self isDisplayingPageForIndex:index]) {
        ImageScrollView *page = [self dequeueRecycledPage];
        if (page == nil) {
            page = [[[ImageScrollView alloc] init] autorelease];
        }
        [self configurePage:page forIndex:index];
        [pagingScrollView addSubview:page];
        [visiblePages addObject:page];
    }
}
```

}

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. If anyone has come across such an issue can share the ideas with me.

Comment: does your showImageWithText method get called? where is imageView created/defined?

Comment: Yes. It is called but I guess I forgot to create and define imageView.

Comment: as Malaxeur says, use : imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]; before you add it to the scrollView. or even better define the UIImageView in your header file.

Comment: Did try that its not working may be I have to add another layer on top of it or something else ?

Comment: maybe the code is working but the image is behind something else? try bringing the subview to the front : [pagingScrollView bringSubviewToFront: imageView];

Comment: failing that, ensure that you are using the correct co-ordinate system - e.g. positioning the image at the correct location in the scrollview when accounting for offset of the scrollview itself. try positioning your scrollview at x=0, y=0 to be sure.

Comment: When I do the tap gesture, I do get the correct co-ordinates by logging the output. But somehow bringSubviewToFront: still doesnot work.I am using CATiledLayer example from apple. I dont know why its not taking the image.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but your imageView is nil.

You add [pagingScrollView addSubview:imageView] however imageView is not instantiated at this point.

Since you're always assigning the same image, you should just do:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

inside of 'loadView' and

```
[imageView release];
imageView = nil;
```

inside of 'viewDidUnload'

Comment: I did try to create an instance of UIImageView but did not help. I have added more code so that it makes more sense I hope.